# Why can javascript integers be specified with an e to signify power of ten?

Tags: javascript, integer

What's the basis for the javascript notation:

```
x = 2.5e3
```

?

For those not up to speed (like me, 10 minutes ago), the value of `x` will be `2500`.

Comment: Apologies if this is a duplicate - I found it very hard to search for `e`!

Comment: Exponential notation like this has been used in programming languages for at least 60 years. It may have come originally from Fortran.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you are looking for. "Because that's how the language is designed" seems rather weak as an answer.

Comment: There are lots of questions that explain what this notation means, but there's probably not a question that explains **why**, so it's probably not a duplicate.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about [a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'm not sure that "Why was this language design decision made?" questions  are a good fit.

Comment: 1e10 is easier to type than 10000000000, probably harder to mistype too

Comment: Unless you get the JS language designer to tell you "why" you are only going to get opinions here. Close.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, this notation is a form of *scientific notation* called *E notation*, and is a standard feature of [most popular programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).